# QT QSqlDatabase connected to MSSql pulls rows EXTREMELY slowly

Tags: sql-server, qt

I am using QT, on a Windows 10 box. I am connecting to a `MS_SQL server` to pull records so that I can relocate them in a Postgres database.

I'm using the `QSqlDatabase` class then an `QSqlQuery` to pull rows. This is shockingly slow ~2 rows / second. I was expecting performance maybe 500 times faster than this. Is this the sort of performance I have to deal with, or am I missing something?

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. This performs at about 2Hz.

```html
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3");
    db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=10.10.1.32;Database=[DB_NAME];Uid=[UID];pwd=[PWD]");

    if (!db.open()) return -1;

    QSqlQuery query;
    bool worked = query.exec("select * from [TABLE_NAME]");
    if (!worked) return -2;

    while(query.next())
    {
        QSqlRecord record = query.record();
        for(int i = 0; i < query.record().count(); i++)
        {
            QVariant value = record.value(i);
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\t",qPrintable(value.toString()));
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The sql is trivial - just selecting a table (not a view). Dealing with tiny amounts of data. A row would be way less than 1kb all columns tallied. The server performs well running this query from the MS database ui.

Comment: I would also add that I wouldn't normally worry over performance, but I have ~100000 rows to liberate. That will take about 14 hours.I was expecting it to take a few minutes. Similar queries on Postgres databases run at that rate.

Comment: To clarify, I did not downvote you. Try `query.prepare("select * from [TABLE_NAME]");` after declaration and afterwards call `bool worked = query.exec();` but I doubt this will increase performance that much.

Comment: The bizarre continues. At this point i've been able to pull 3000 records out of the ms sql db. That has taken 45 minutes. The program is building an update script for postgres. that is being executed in < 2 seconds. Something is majorly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a buddy of mine figured things out. As it turns out, the default for QQuery is to use a bi-directional cursor - at least with the ODBC driver.

The QQuery has a property "forwardOnly". Set that to true, and while the code doesn't speed up 500X (like I was expecting), it does speed up 250X. Yeah... no exaggeration.

Here's the mod to the example above.

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.setForwardOnly(true);
bool worked = query.exec("select * from [TABLE_NAME]");
```